# Multiple file upload on web server through android app

Tags: java, android, multithreading, file-upload, for-loop

**Please can anyone provide me explanation in corresponding to method call stack**

Hello there I am developing an android app in which I haver to upload some mp3 files on server

This is the the function given me to me for uploading the files

**uploadToServer(String arg1, String arg2)**

Now I have to send multiple upload request. I have two ArrayList of arg1 and arg2

So I am using an for loop for iterating ArrayList and sending uploading request.

So Now the problem is before first upload gets completed second starts automatically. I havent implemented threads. So why it is happening . According to call stacks concept until the first request gets over Second can.t be started. How come the second iteration of for loops gets started until the first gets finished.

Comment: Could be that the uploadToServer is asynchronous, i.e. it returns without completing...

Comment: @ThaMe90 Yes the method is asynchronous. But if its execution is not finished How come the program execution is going back to the for loop

Comment: Asynchronous means the operation will return before it is completed. It will generally fire off an event or call a callback method when it has completed.

Comment: If it were a synchronous method, it would return upon completion.

Comment: @ThaMe90 But according to the concept of method call stack first the method execution has to get completed.

Comment: I suggest reading up on asynchronousness on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_method_invocation). Short summary is: an asynchronous method will return before the started action completes so your application doesn't have to wait for completion of said action. It is handled in some background thread that will signal you when the action completes.

Comment: @ThaMe90 of thanks for helping + 1 for your helpful comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness:

An asynchronous method will return before the action it starts completes. This is perfectly fine the method has done what it should have: start a background task that performs the action.

So in short, an asynchronous method is just an initiator for a separate (anonymous) thread that handles the action. When completed, it either fires off an event, or call a callback method (depending on the used programming language).

[Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_method_invocation)

Comment: But what will happen to call stack. +1 for you answer regarding asycc concepts

Comment: Nothing special in any case. It behaves the same as when you call any other method. It returns when it has finished spawning a separate thread that handles the action that you want to happen. So after the method spawned the thread, it completes/returns, and thus is removed from the call stack.